# I am not able to install SDK command tool with add-ons

Tags: android-sdk-tools, build-tools

- I have successfully installed java. Set the variable path, check java version in the command .
- Now, download .zip file for SDK tool on windows 32.
- Extract the file and saved it. Now, I want to install `Platform-tool` and `build-tool`. I am able to install `Platform-tools` from the command prompt. But, when I try to install `Build-tools`, it says it is not there. I need to install `Appium` once I get it right.

  > C:\sdktools\tools\bin>sdkmanager.bat "Build-tools"
  > Warning: File C:\Users\Aradhana.android\repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
  > Warning: Failed to find package Build-tools
  > [===                                    ] 10% Computing updates..
- I also get following error message in my command prompt
  androidrepositry is not found.

Comment: https://androidsdkmanager.azurewebsites.net/Buildtools or just download and add ? the needed versions are tehre

Answer (score 4):

There is no sdk package with the name `build-tools`. They are versioned in the package system. So you need to install it with a name like this `build-tools;28.0.1` (the latest version currently). 
Platform-tools, however, do not have that kind of versioning. There is just one platform-tools package present and it has the name `platform-tools`. That's why that works.

To check out, what you can install via the sdk manager you can pass the `--list` flag.

The warning about the repositories file should not cause any problems (at least I never faced a problem due with that warning). You can, however, create an empty repositories file, if you want to avoid the warning.

Answer (score 0):

build-tools is not a package name in sdk. Sdk packages are named together with there version number, so including the version number is necessary. Therefore, you should use

```
 build-tools;29.0.2  #this is currently the latest version available
```