# buldozer or sdkmanager Buildozer failed to execute

Tags: python, android, linux, sdk, buildozer

I try to run buildozer on my linux to make an App from python-kivy. I got this error:

First I have these warnings:

```
Warning: File /home/kouhi/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.        
Warning: Failed to download any source lists!                                   
Warning: Failed to find package tools
```

And then these errors:

```
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     XDG_SEAT = 'seat0'
#     QT4_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/usr/share/upstart/xdg:/etc/xdg'
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     XDG_SESSION_PATH = '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0'
#     PATH = '/home/kouhi/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/kouhi/bin:/home/kouhi/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
```

then lots of errors in the middle, and at the end I have:

```
#     LC_NUMERIC = 'fa_IR'
#     VTE_VERSION = '4205'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     QT_LINUX_ACCESSIBILITY_ALWAYS_ON = '1'
#     QT_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     WINDOWID = '92275921'
#     GDMSESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     INSTANCE = ''
#     QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
#     GTK_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'
#     LC_NAME = 'fa_IR'
#     LC_MONETARY = 'fa_IR'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Any kind of help is very appreciated. I have no idea what to do. thanks. 
Are these the results of Warnings? What should I do to fix them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am not able to install SDK command tool with add-ons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51283357/i-am-not-able-to-install-sdk-command-tool-with-add-ons)

Comment: @Zydnar that was not my question, and also it was not related to my question here. Any way, thanks.      I think my problem is that packages cannot be installed through terminal, while I have to use vpn and I do not have it.

Comment: Error message is similar, I know it's not your question, have you checked it?

Comment: @Zydnar  great thanks for your time. Actually, it was different. I solved my problem using vpn. It seems that my place is under sanction!   Politicians fight, people should pay!!!